# Trying to output a list using class

Tags: python, class

I am trying to get the moving average of a price, but I keep getting an attribute error in my `Moving_Average` class:

```
'Moving_Average' object has no attribute 'days'
```

Here is what I have:

```
class Moving_Average:

    def calculation(self, alist:list,days:int):
        m = self.days
        prices = alist[1::2]
        average = [0]* len(prices)
        signal = ['']* len(prices)
        for m in range(0,len(prices)-days+1):
            average[m+2] = sum(prices[m:m+days])/days
            if prices[m+2] < average[m+2]:
                signal[m+2]='SELL'
            elif prices[m+2] > average[m+2] and prices[m+1] < average[m+1]:
                signal[m+2]='BUY'
            else:
                signal[m+2] =''
        return average,signal

def print_report(symbol:str,strategy:str):
        print('SYMBOL: ', symbol)
        print('STRATEGY: ', strategy)
        print('Date            Closing        Strategy        Signal')


def user():
    strategy = '''
    Which of the following strategy would you like to use?
    * Simple Moving Average [S]
    * Directional Indicator[D]

    Please enter your choice: '''

    if signal_strategy in 'Ss':
        days = input('Please enter the number of days for the average')
        days = int(days)
        strategy = 'Simple Moving Average {}-days'.format(str(days))
        m = Moving_Average()
        ma = m.calculation(gg, days)
        print(ma)
```

gg is an list that contains date and prices.

```
[2013-10-01,60,2013-10-02,60]
```

The output is supposed to look like:

```
 Date       Price      Average      Signal
2013-10-01   60.0                       
2013-10-02   60.0       60.00         BUY
```

Comment: The Moving_Average class only has Calculation. The print function is not a part of it.

Comment: why is this a `class`?

Comment: Please fix the indentation. I can guess that `calculation` is supposed to be a method of the class, but is `print_report`—which is indented _more_ than `calculation`—a top-level function? Is that `if` supposed to be inside `print_report`, or is it module-level code?

Comment: print_report() and user() are in a different module.

Comment: This line `m = self.days` does nothing because `m` is overwritten as soon as the for-loop is reached.  In fact, removing it will not impact the script at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `days` which is an argument of the `calculation` function not an instance variable of the class. You don't need to use `self.days` to access it just use `m = days`

Comment: Hi ramirez...if I do that I get the following error in the calculation function:   User_interface(),
    ma = m.calculation(gg, days), 
    average[m+2] = sum(prices[m:m+days])/days....
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: That looks like another problem with your code somewhere else. I don't see that part in the code you posted. Update your question.

Comment: @captainmorgan: When your code is broken, fixing one bug often just exposes the next bug. That doesn't mean the fix was wrong. This answer solves the problem you asked about, and explains why it does so. The fact that it doesn't magically fix all of the rest of your code, even the parts we haven't seen, doesn't mean it's not a complete answer.

Comment: @ramirez the problem I believe is in the calculation function.

Comment: Python error messages are quite informative once you realize that they are. It's telling you you have an `int` and `str` and you are trying to add them together. What is in your list `gg`? Strings?

Comment: Where have you got `signal_strategy` ? It's not specified in your code.

Comment: @ratatoskar..yes the list gg contains strings.

Comment: You can't add strings and integers together. Are you trying to concatenate the string and the integer ?? try using `str(days)`

Comment: `sum(prices[m:m+days])` is attempting to sum a list of strings with a start value of 0 (that's the default). I think you want your list to be numbers, not strings. Something like `gg = [float(i) for i in gg]` might be what you want.